# .match for regular expression isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, match

I'm trying to use a regular expression validation using .match for email validation and for some reason it only shows invalid even though all formats are followed!

javascript function

```
function check_email_valid(emails) {
        var emailRegex = '^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$';
        if (emails.match(emailRegex)) {
            jQuery('#<%=Label16.ClientID%>').css('color', 'green');
            jQuery('#<%=Label16.ClientID%>').show();
            jQuery('#<%=Label16.ClientID%>').text("Valid Email!");
        }
        else {
            jQuery('#<%=Label16.ClientID%>').css('color', 'red');
            jQuery('#<%=Label16.ClientID%>').show();
            jQuery('#<%=Label16.ClientID%>').text("Invalid Email!");
        }
```

Event trigger

```
 $('#<%=TextBox8.ClientID%>').keyup(function () {
            var email = jQuery('#<%=TextBox8.ClientID%>').val();
            check_email_valid(email);
        });
```

I keyed in test@mail.com and got "Invalid Email!". Any idea why?

Comment: The pattern doesn't match `test@mail.com` - I use [RegExr](http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/) for testing my patterns.

Comment: Biotox>Great website! Will use it in the future! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JavaScript has a slightly different way of defining regex patterns than other languages. They're not strings, but instead simply start with a slash, end with one, and after that you can specify some flags.

Your pattern is defined like this:

```
var emailRegex = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
```

The i flag at the end of the pattern makes it case insensitive.

Comment: Worked well for me! Didnt know the pattern for jquery regex is written that way. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Case-sensitivity.... And validating email addresses is [a bit more complicated](http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html) then that... (.museum for one, but there is more..).

Comment: Thanks for the case sensitivty help, was one of the error! Changed it already :)

Comment: You need to pay attention here -- what you are attempting is a fool's errand -- you're only going to annoy users when they input their perfectly valid e-mail adress and you tell them its invalid -- most commercial websites have you enter your e-mail twice and then compare them to ensure they are entered the same both times